# Can't connect to MongoDB Server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My nodejs app can't connect to MondoDB Server.

I have already allowed all ip addresses (0.0.0.0/0) to connect.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const URL = '' //database url

mongoose.connect(URL, {useNewUrlParser: true}).then(db => {
    console.log("Connected")
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

Above code throws "MongooseServerSelectionError: connection timed out" error

Comment: Are you getting any error logged in the `catch` statement

Comment: It says "MongooseServerSelectionError: connection timed out"

Answer (score 0):

U have to provide URL in mongoose something like this

const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp'

But before that please verify whether the mongo is running in your system or not.

Comment: I am trying to connect to cloud server and I have provided the required url. Removed here for security reasons

Comment: Can you connect it via any mongo IDE like compass?

Comment: There seems to be some issue with ip address even though I have whitelisted all ips. 
I can connect in normal circumstance but as soon as my ip changes(Heroku), I get error.